# Riddle answer with hints

Tags: discussion, formatting

**In an answer to a riddle, is it appropriate to post the hint(s) as a line of the answer?**

---

Say there is a riddle (**not [my](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5801/30903) riddle**):

> > His name sounds like a card game,
> >     His mother came from Scotland,
> >     He's talked about building a wall,
> >     And created a ban on entry.
>
> Hint:
>
> > He is famous on the media.

And I answer as follows:

> The answer is:
>
> > Donald Trump
>
> His name sounds like a card game
>
> > Trumps is a type of card game
>
> His mother came from Scotland
>
> > Well, she did
>
> He's talked about building a wall
>
> > Specifically, between the US and Mexico
>
> And created a ban on entry
>
> > Citizens of certain countries cannot enter the US anymore (give or take a few exceptions)

Should I do this for the last part:

> (Hint)
>
> > *He is famous on the media*
> > He has recently been on the media a lot — type in trump into the google search bar and two of the suggestions (for me) are these:
> >  [image: News]

Or this?

> He is famous on the media
>
> > (Ditto)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When answering a riddle like this, I normally **hide the hint itself as well as its explanation** in my answer ([example](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/13217/5373)).

It's just good manners: the reason for spoilertagging the hint in the original question is so that people can have a go at solving the riddle *without seeing the hint* if they want to, and if the OP has gone to the trouble of hiding it in their question, then why reveal it in an answer unless you have to?

It also doesn't detract from the answer in any way: if somebody wants to see the line-by-line solution to the riddle, they'll have to check all the spoilertags anyway, and adding the unhidden text of the hint to the answer doesn't tell a reader anything about the solution. Only the explanation of the hint does that, and you're already assuming spoilertagging of all explanations.